# What is the idiom for the situation "If people-in-authority don't follow their own set rules then what can one expect from rest of us"

Tags: expressions, idioms

What is the idiom for a situation that "If people-in-authority don't follow their own set rules, then what can one expect from rest of us" in similar examples given below in different settings:

When HR themselves are tardy, undisciplined then what can you expect from the employees (punctuality and discipline)?

When traffic police themselves are offending (driving without belts, smoking while driving) what can you expect from the vehicle driving community in the city?

When parents themselves are undisciplined (smoking in front of children), what can you expect from the children themselves?

When the management is insincere, what can you expect from their staff?

Comment: The general comment is often "do as I say, not as I do!" when parents are telling their children how to behave...

Comment: or the old `If Johnny jumped off a cliff, would you jump too?` .... or `Monkey see, monkey do! Don't be a monkey!`

Comment: Somewhat related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/392311/if-the-cedars-caught-fire-what-will-the-hyssops-of-the-wall-say

Comment: @jsotola [This is now the goto answer to the "if all your friends" question.](https://xkcd.com/1170/)

Comment: When a word or phrase request attracts a long list of ideas, that is a clear signal that either the criteria are unclear or the question is being taken as more of a poll or request for a list of things, neither of which are a good fit for the Stack Exchange model. The word request must be narrow and specific enough that it has one clearly correct answer. It must for example identify the desired connotation, register, and part of speech, and the context in which the word or phrase is to be used.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Do as I say, not as I do**

> Model yourself after my instructions, not my actions. The phrase implies that the speaker is imperfect and makes mistakes, so one should follow their advice but not imitate them. My dad, a big smoker, always told me not to smoke. "Do as I say, not as I do," he used to say.

Better quote:

> Prov. Take my advice, even though I am acting contrary to it. (Sometimes used as an apology for behaving hypocritically.) Jill: Why are you walking on the grass when I told you not to? Jane: But you're walking on the grass. Jill: Do as I say, not as I do.

[free dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/do+as+I+say%2C+not+as+I+do)

Generally, in British English, this is always used from either a superior point of view, as a reply to a comment about how the figure of authority is doing something they've told people not to do... Or it's used as a pejorative term from those below the person who is "doing", often with sarcasm:

> So it's a case of "Do as I say, not as I do" then is it?

Comment: I don't think this quite captures the desired tenor.  The implication in the OP is that the people breaking the rules can't/shouldn't expect anyone else to follow them; basically that through their actions the person in the position of authority has ceded their authority.  This expression doesn't seem to capture this, at least not in the context of the example provided (where the advice being given is actually sound, due to factual health-related things that stand independently of any 'rules').

Comment: I agree with you 100%. In fact, it's almost opposite.

Comment: It's still hypocrisy, either way...

Comment: @RemarkLima If you are honest about your double standards then it's not hypocrisy. Hypocrisy ('play acting') involves presenting a false impression of yourself and _misleading_ people.

Comment: OK, in that case, double standards. Which, IMHO is frowned on the same as hypocrisy :-)

Answer (score 54):

While not an exact fit (because it doesn't necessarily involve figures of authority), what about the following:

> *If they don't **practice what they preach** why should we?*

from def:

> To do the things that you advise other people to do:
>
> He's such a hypocrite! He never practises what he preaches.

(Cambridge)

Also, while not an idiom, *hypocrite* fits as well.

Comment: I definitely think this involves figures of authority. The one who preaches is most typically _the_ preacher, the moral and often de facto leader in a community.

Answer (score 35):

A “[double standard](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/double-standard)” might be the appropriate term.

> a rule or standard of good behaviour that, unfairly, some people are expected to follow or achieve but other people are not:

as in:

> - *The governor is being accused of (having) double standards in being tough on law and order yet allowing his own cabinet members to escape prosecution for fraud.*

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: Double standard is a bit more general than this. It's also a double standard if you have different rules for men versus woman, for instance.

Answer (score 23):

***"[Lead by example](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lead%20by%20example),"*** is a common phrase - often used in management training. The idea is that underlings will emulate the behavior of their perceived superiors in matters of dress and decorum in a particular setting. It worked better in the days before "sensitivity training".

(M-W)

Comment: @user070221 - Thanks for the edit. (Besides not knowing how to do research, I have a mortal fear of plagiarizing.)

Comment: If you provide a link and say where it comes from, I doubt you may be accused of plagiarism.

Comment: I'm confused by your last sentence and what it's supposed to imply.

Comment: Underlings?  Lol, glad I don't work in an office anymore.

Comment: @V2Blast - Somehow, I doubt that.

Comment: @Oldbag Why? I too can, at best, take wild guesses as to what you mean. It would be great if you could elaborate.

Comment: Another vote for confusion at your last sentence. The answer is otherwise good.

Comment: I too fail to see how sensitivity training has reduced the efficiency of leading by example. As far as I know, leading by example is often **part** of sensitivity training.

Comment: *Sigh* I am confounded as to how many educated people declare themselves unable to see another side of something. I'll put it this way: You have just landed the job of your dreams... Picture in your mind a person or group that you have been directed to be "sensitive" toward.  Keeping in mind that you are anxious to be successful - is the aforementioned person or group going to be the model you emulate? Most Americans have ancestors that had to modify certain customs or behaviors publicly in order to advance their positions socially and economically.

Comment: (cont.) Behaving tolerantly toward ignorance - or what would be perceived as "odd" behavior -is always selective.  Would you tolerate it in a friend - assuming that you wanted them to thrive in society - or, would you call them out on it?  I find the concept that certain people must be "tolerated" bigoted in itself. This is not an argument, I am merely presenting my opinion for clarification.

Comment: "Most Americans have ancestors that had to modify certain customs or behaviors publicly in order to advance their positions socially and economically." Just because they had to do it doesn't necessarily mean they should have had to. Things happening in some way in the past is not by itself a reason for them having to happen in the same way now. People kept slaves in the past, does that mean it's okay to allow slavery now? (This, of course, is not intended to make assumptions about those those people who modified their behaviors and customs because they wanted to, not just because they had to.)

Comment: I suspect that sort of perspective (which could probably be elaborated on, but comments aren't the place for that) is why some found your last sentence confusing.

Answer (score 16):

***[Set a bad example](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bad+example)*** is an  expression you may use.

***set an example:***

> set a good or bad example . Behave in a way that should (or will) be imitated, as in
>
> - Dad was always telling Bill to set a good example for his younger brother, or ***They were afraid of setting a bad example for the other nations/***. [Late 1700s]

(AHD)

Answer (score 14):

The more colloquial idiom would be "**Sauce for the Goose, is sauce for the Gander**"

That is, rules that apply to those under authority must also apply to those in authority. Or, rules that apply to me must also apply to you.

All the other phrases are correct as well.  A common idea with many expressions.

Another expression of this from US Colonial times:

> "The Law condemns the man or woman
>
> Who steals the goose from off the Common
>
> But lets the greater villain loose,
>
> Who steals the Common from the goose."

Comment: I've never heard this expression before (which certainly doesn't mean it's not a valid answer). What part of the world is this used in?

Comment: @Belgabad: As someone who grew up in the UK in the 80’s/90’s, this expression comes very naturally to me — I’d think of it as very common but perhaps a little old fashioned.  It was my first thought for the question too — it’s not quite as specific as what the question asks for, but it fits an aspect which most other answers miss, in that it describes not just the double standard itself, but the response of flouting the double standard.

Comment: @PLL I grew up in the United States, so if that's a UK specific expression, that makes a lot of sense. You learn something new every day :D

Comment: From the US, my experience is the variant _What's good for the goose is good for the gander_ is what is used, I've never heard this one with sauces.

Comment: @JeffLambert same here, but I'm from UK

Comment: I don't think the "sauce for the goose" quote is any more apt or anywhere near as common  as the other suggestions but I've always liked that rhyme. :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's an exact idiom, but [this](http://www.shakespeare-online.com/quickquotes/quickquotehamletprimrose.html) quote from Shakespeare sums up what you were trying to express:

> Do not, as some ungracious pastors do,
>
> Show me the steep and thorny way to heaven,
>
> Whiles, like a puffed and reckless libertine,
>
> Himself the primrose path of dalliance treads,
>
> And recks not his own rede.
>
> <sub>*Ophelia to Laertes - Hamlet 1.3.48-52*</sub>

Comment: This is a useful post, but note that our EL&U site is devoted to *detailed* answers. Please cite which character and which play. For further guidance, see [answer].

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can say

HR has an attitude of "**rules for thee, but not for me**".

Comment: See also: "One [law] for the rich, another [law] for the poor"

Answer (score 2):

**a fish rots from the head down**

> When an organization or state fails, it is the leadership that is the root cause.

It's more on a leadership, but I believe it could do.

Examples:

> 1. The company was bound to be closed sooner or later considering the kind of mangers that they had hired. A fish rots from the head down after all.
> 2. A leader has to be of a strong will and good character otherwise as it is said, the fish rots from the head down. The whole organization would then have to suffer because of it.
> 3. His maid servant doesn’t do anything as asked for. But the fish rots from the head down, look at how unorganized his own life is.

Source: [theidioms.com](https://www.theidioms.com/fish-rots-from-the-head-down/)

Answer (score 1):

My favourite idiom that I believe is applicable here is [*Physician heal thyself*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physician,_heal_thyself)

> > The moral of the proverb is counsel to attend to one's own defects rather than criticizing defects in others

Also loosely related: [*First remove the log from your own eye*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthew_7:5)

> > You hypocrite! First remove the beam out of your own eye,
> >     and then you can see clearly to remove the speck out of your brother’s eye.

Answer (score 1):

***That's rich**, HR complaining about my punctuality.
**That's rich**, the traffic police telling me to use a belt.*

From [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=That%27s%20rich) :

> **that's rich**
> when someone criticizes you for something that they themselves do.
>
> when someone has the audacity to reprimand you when they are much worse than you.
>
> *Tony: Dude, you were wrong for standing up Kesley the other night.
>
> John: Yet you're engaged yet you're f***ing two of your fiancee's best friends! That's rich, bro. Real f***ing rich.*
>
> [...]
>
> by mizzraynay June 29, 2006